# Reddit API v1 - Forbidden by administrative rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, reddit

Hi I am trying to access my informations via authenticated request to the API.
I am working with Rails to do so, with no sucess, so I tried with Curl and got this:

```
Request:
curl -X GET -L "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me?access_token=BLURED_ACCESS_TOKEN" -A "webapp:integrationproject:v1.0 (by /u/Lupins)"

Response:
<html><body><h1>403 Forbidden</h1>
Request forbidden by administrative rules.
</body></html>
```

I am trying to do the same with Rails with no success, this is what it looks like in Rails:

```
user_agent = 'WebApp:IntegrationProject:v1.0 (by /u/Lupins)'

response = RestClient.get "https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/me?access_token=#{auth}", user_agent: user_agent
```

I get the same forbidden error.
Can anyone help me to access this properly?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/2nmhdi/403_request_forbidden_by_administrative_rules/ seems to indicate that you're using the wrong grant type... could be the same problem for you - read the comments on the above and see if it helps you?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Needed to send this string as header: Authorization: bearer BLURED_ACCESS_TOKEN